# Colorpicker plugin for sublime text 2

Tags: plugins, sublime-text

I have installed Sublime text 2 in my ubuntu 12.04.

But I can't install a colorpick plugin for the sublime. I downloaded a zip file from github named: 'Package Control Sublime-package'. But I can't install the plugin.

Can anyone please help me???

Answer (score 0):

First Install package Control [via these instructions](http://wbond.net/sublime_packages/package_control/installation) take note that the instructions need to happen **inside** sublime and not in the console.

Then menu system-> Install Package -> Color Pick and see what's there.